# Basic Math in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, math

This question is probably so simple I should be embarrassed to ask, but all my searches for answers only came up with structuring complex math expressions in RoR - what I need help on is far more basic.

I have a Rails 4 app that is basically creating invoices.  Each `line_item` has a `price`, a `units`, and a `tax`.  I need to multiply `price` by `units`, multiply that times `tax` if my `taxable` boolean is true and add it up to come up with my `total`.

Where I'm struggling is figuring out how to structure these calculations and probably equally as important, where to even place them in my code so that it saves to the db.  My inclination is to put them in the model, but even that I'm unsure of.

My attempt at doing it myself was by adding a basic function into the controller:

```
def create
@line_item = LineItem.new(line_item_params)
@line_item.invoice_id = @invoice
@line_item.total = @line_item.price * @line_item.units

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

If someone can show me an example, or some resources that discuss basic math in Ruby, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it was best to do the math in the model with an `before_save` command:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invoice
    before_save :calculate_total_amount

    def calculate_total_amount
        if price.present? && units.present?
            self.total = price * units
        end
    end
end
```